# Plot timeline with python showing how often each date occurs in given series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need a simple timeline plot. The input is a series with dates where some of them occur multiple times. The plot should represent how often the dates occur and there are no labels needed for the number of occurrences.

At the moment I am using the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def timeline(series, formatString):
    fig = plt.figure(dpi=100)
    fig.tight_layout(pad=10)
    plt.clf()
    plt.title("test")
    series = pd.to_datetime(series, format=formatString, errors='ignore')

    plt.title("timeline")

    plt.plot(series, np.zeros_like(series), "-o", color="k", markerfacecolor="r")

    ax = plt.gca()

    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)


    return fig
```

The code produces the following plot.

[image]

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this and also visualize how often each date occurs?

Comment: You should be using [seaborn countplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html). Ex. `sns.countplot(x=df["Date"])`